# How i can block requests for a specific page?

Tags: url, block, ubuntu-14.04, joomla3.1, mod-security2

I would like to completely delete or block access to a specific page in my site.

More specifically, I have seen this exploit "**Joomla COM_MEDIA Exploit**" : http://all1gat0r.blogspot.gr/2013/08/joomla-commedia-exploit.html

and from what I see, there is the page : `/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&fieldid=&e_name=jform_articletext&asset=com_content&author=&folder=`

The exploit does not work on me, but anyway I want to **completely remove the above page**.
How can I do this?

Web Server : **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** ( *with installed **Mod Security2*** )
Web Site : **Joomla 3.1.5**

Answer (score 0):

Is there any single parameter plus value which makes this URL dangerous?

Then you could write a rule using ARGS:parameterName (https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#ARGS) to block the request.

Ronald